# How to set specific color for each category when using "pygal.maps.world" drawing world map?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygal

Does anyone use `pygal.maps.world` in `pygal` to draw a world map?
I have 5 different categories that includes several countries for each category. How can I set specific color for each category?

Below are part of my code:

> ```
> supra = pygal.maps.world.SupranationalWorld()
> supra.add('Asia', Asia_list)
> supra.add('Europe', Europe_list)
> supra.add('Africa', Africa_list)
> supra.render()
> ```

`Asia_list`, `Europe_list`, and `Africa_list` are three lists I defined that include certain countries.

How can I set color by myself?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can override the default colors that pygal will use with the `Style` class.  The format I used below is by assigning a hex triplet value for the first three colors pygal will use.  To add more colors, just add more to the list.  For more info on a hex triplet, this wikipedia page can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Here are the Style changes:

```
from pygal.style import Style
custom_style = Style(colors=('#FFFF00', '#00FFFF', '#FF00FF'))
```

Second, I was not able to do this style change with the SupranationalWorld like your example above, but I was able to just use the following which I believe does what you requested:

```
worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World(style=custom_style)
worldmap_chart.add('Asia', Asia_list)
worldmap_chart.add('Europe', Europe_list)
worldmap_chart.add('Africa', Africa_list)
worldmap_chart.render_to_file('world.svg')
```

The documentation for all the things you can customize with style can be found here: http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/custom_styles.html